# three separate forms one submit button

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, submit

I've tried a few different methods, but so far nothing is working.

I have 3 different forms.

When you click on form A. it'll drop down and allow people to fill it out.

when you click on form B. it'll hide form A. and drop down form b. for people to fill out.

Now with this method I would like to have one submit button at the bottom.

But i'm not sure how to make each form send separately with one submit.

I know it can be done. but, i can't get it to work.

I am still very new to a lot of this.

Here's the code I'm using to try and do this with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            $.post($("#simple").attr("action"), $("#simple").serialize(),
              function () { });

            $.post($("#complete").attr("action"), $("#simple").serialize(),
              function () {    });

              $.post($("#Miscellaneous").attr("action"), $("#simple").serialize(),
              function () {});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#submit").click(function () {$('#form1').submit();$('#form2').submit();$('#form3').submit(); });` try

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The code is untested though.

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form1').submit();
    $('#form2').submit();
    $('#form3').submit();
})​
```

EDIT: This might also help you to select the nth element if you prefer https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I'll try this!!
Quick question. should i have the submit button info within 'form 1' or outside all forms?

Comment: Doesn't matter where. the e.preventDefault will halt the normal execution of the submit button so it will not do anything else except what you tell it to do. Although personally I would put it outside all forms, just feels nicer that way

Comment: okay. so i place the codes. and added the submit button below the three different forms. but,w hen clicking the submit button, nothing happens?

Comment: open the javascript console (press f12). are there any errors?

Comment: oh goodness me. yes!! there are errors.i dont even know how to go about them

Comment: It looks like it's just complaining about a semicolon.

Comment: Hmm i tried adding on, but it was still complaining. I'll try it again just in case though!